# MVVM Navigation from ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `MainWindow` that has it's own `ViewModel` that I want to use for navigation purposes. It looks like so:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    SelectedViewModel = new LoginViewModel();

    DashboardCommand = new DelegateCommand(OpenDashboard);
}

private object _selectedViewModel;

public object SelectedViewModel
{
    get => _selectedViewModel;
    set
    {
        _selectedViewModel = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedViewModel");
    }
}


public ICommand DashboardCommand { get; set; }

private void OpenDashboard(object obj)
{
    SelectedViewModel = new DashboardViewModel();
}
```

I have a `LoginView` that hosts a `UserControl` with a simple form that lets users enter their details, and click a `Button` to login. When the user clicks the `Button` a check is performed and, if it passes, I would like to navigate to the `DashboardView` from the `LoginViewModel`. This is a snippet of the `LoginViewModel`:

```
#region Login
private DelegateCommand _loginCommand;
public ICommand RegisterCommand
{
    get
    {
        _loginCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => Login());
        return _loginCommand;
    }
}

private void Login()
{
    if (LoginCheck())
    {
        // TODO: Navigate to the DashboardView
    }
}
#endregion
```

My question is how can I navigate on the `MainWindowViewModel` from the `LoginViewModel`?

Comment: https://www.mesta-automation.com/wpf-navigation-with-dependency-injection-diioc-part-1/

Comment: How about using DI to allow viewmodels to know of each other, and viewmodels know of their views (windows).

Comment: `LoginViewModel` hosts `UserControl`? That's not MvvM. `UserControl` can not be anywhere near the `ViewModel`.If however UserControl uses LoginViewModel as it's DataContext that's different. You could use an event on the LoginViewModel to when user is logged in and handle that in the MainViewModel.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Apologies for not being clear. Your second statement is correct, `LoginView` hosts a `UserControl` that uses `LoginViewModel` as its datacontext.

Comment: Ah, OK. You can still use an event from `LoginViewModel` in your `MainWindowViewModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is a good example of when to use messaging in MVVM.

When the check is performed and passed you should send a message from the LoginViewModel. MainWindowViewModel should register for this message and do the navigation.

To use messaging you can use the Publish/Subscribe pattern. To do this you do not have to implement it. You can use several MVVM librarys that implements is.

For example you can use MVVM Light:

Inherit your ViewModel from `ViewModelBase`, then you have a `MessengerInstance` that you can use to send and register for messages.

Your code in LoginViewModel when check is passed:

```
MessengerInstance.Send(new NavigateToViewNotification(){ToView="Dashboard"});
```

Your code in MainWindowViewModel (in consturctor):

```
MessengerInstance.Register<NavigateToViewNotification>(this, ntv=> {/* here imlement the navigation ntv.ToView has the info to which view*/});
```

`NavigateToViewNotification` is your own class:

```
public class NavigateToViewNotification
{
    public string ToView { get; set; }
}
```

This way you avoid having direct references between ViewModels that will result in loosely coupled ViewModels and thus more easily maintainable client code.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how can I navigate on the MainWindowViewModel from the LoginViewModel?

Three options.

1. Keep a strong reference to the `MainWindowViewModel` from the `LoginViewModel` by for example injecting the former with an instance of the latter when you create it:

   ```
   public LoginViewModel(MainWindowViewModel vm)
   {
       _vm = vm;
   }
   ```

This creates a strong coupling between the the two types, or rather any child view model type that is supposed to be able to navigate and the `MainWindowViewModel`.

2. Use a messenger or an event aggregator and send a navigation message from the `LoginViewModel` to the `MainWindowViewModel`: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/.

This removes the strong coupling between the view model types but makes the code a bit more complex since there is no longer a direct reference to the `MainWindowViewModel` where the navigation occurs.

The `LoginViewModel` just raises an event using the event aggregator and then it doesn't really care about who, if any, actually handles that message and performs the actual navigation.

3. Use a shared navigation service that you inject both view models with. They then navigate through this service, rather than navigating through the `MainWindowViewModel`.

This makes all view models loosely coupled from each other. They only know about and have a dependency upon the shared service.